# Java Azure SDK: how to remove VMs in a batch

Tags: java, azure

Java Azure SDK has methods to create resources in a batch like
`CreatedResources<ResourceT> create(List<Creatable<ResourceT>> creatables);`
but for VMs and other resource types there are only methods to delete a resource one by one like `ServiceCall<Void> deleteByGroupAsync(String groupName, String name, ServiceCallback<Void> callback);`. When I call `deleteByGroupAsync` without waiting for a resource to be deleted I get the exception (see below). Is there a method to delete VMs, NICs, disks, etc in a batch and not one by one?

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Sequence contains no elements
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:115)
    at rx.internal.operators.DeferredScalarSubscriber.complete(DeferredScalarSubscriber.java:83)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTakeLastOne$TakeLastOneSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeTakeLastOne.java:55)
    at rx.Completable$30.onCompleted(Completable.java:2088)
    at rx.Completable$10$1.onCompleted(Completable.java:577)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:857)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:656)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:568)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorMerge.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeMap.java:97)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:75)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:110)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(OperatorTake.java:80)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeFilter.java:76)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:511)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:466)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:244)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:511)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:466)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:244)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:173)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:248)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:148)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:244)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$ScalarAsyncProducer.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:200)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$2$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:114)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to delete all resouces like VMs, NICs, disks for your VMs all at the once, if they are all in a resource group, the only way is delete the resource group as the [explaination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups#ResourceGroups_Delete) for the delete resource group REST API reference said as below.

[image]

There is the offical [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-java-manage-resource-group/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/samples/ManageResourceGroup.java) for deleting resource group which I think it's very helpful for you.

And as references, there are two offical sample codes which introduce how to manage [VM](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-virtual-machines-in-parallel) & [VM with network](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-virtual-machines-with-network-in-parallel) in parallel for creating, but these delete operations are all doing via the resouce group delete operation. But I think the delete operation is an inverse operation of the create operation, so these parallel samples may be also helpful.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the answer. However, I know how to delete a resource group programmatically. However, I do not want to delete all elements from a res. group. My scenario is to extend and existing cluster of VMs and to shrink it when required. I don't know: is it possible to create VMs in a different res. group but use network, load balancer, etc. from another res. group?

Comment: Resource Groups per subscription: 800 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#resource-group-limits and seems like I can use network, etc from another resource group (checked via Azure web interface). I will try.

Comment: failed: cannot reuse the availability set from other resource group (required for load balancer).